# Multidimensional array with date and numbers

Tags: arduino-uno, array

I would like to create something similar to a multidimensional array.
I would like to get this effect.

```
setting = [
     0 => [// 0 is the day of the week, but it can be a number
         '1:25' => 25, // key is time. The value is a number (temperature)
         '7:12' => 22,
         '15: 30 '=> 21,
         '18: 00 '=> 23
         '22: 25 '=> 22
     ]
     1 => [
         '1:25' => 25,
         '7:00' => 21,
         '15: 00 '=> 22,
         '18: 00 '=> 25
         '22: 25 '=> 22
     ]
     2 => [
         '1:25' => 25,
         '7:00' => 21,
         '15: 32 '=> 21,
         '18: 40 '=> 25
         '22: 25 '=> 22
     ]
     .
     .
     .
     e.t.c
];
```

Then I would like to read these values. Days of the week and time are already downloading, but I do not know how to make such a board. I would like to download these values (temperature) to a variable.
Regards

Comment: what board are you talking about?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It seems like you are suffering from an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you're trying to solve a problem that stems from you trying to solve a different problem in the wrong way.

Comment: @jsotola Excuse me. I dealt with the project for work and forgot about my problem. I want to do this on Arduino UNO.

Comment: @Majenko This is not a problem of this type. The question is how to make such an array and how to read such values afterwards.

Comment: I would say you don't want to make an array like that.

Comment: @Majenko It may be different. I will download the temperature and the current time. I will fire the relay by time and temperature. I am taking the current time and temperature all the time. At 12 o'clock, if the temperature is less than 22 degrees, I would like the relay to turn on and heat until it reaches 22 degrees. By 16 o'clock I would like the relay to turn on when the temperature is less than 20 degrees, etc. And that's why I'm asking how to make such an array.

Regards

Comment: Then you should investigate `struct` and arrays (of fixed size) or *linked lists* (for variable size - not recommended on small Arduinos).

Comment: It just combines with `struct`, but I don't know how to "rewrite" the array I wrote in the first post to `struct`.